# How to let users change site language?

Tags: php, multi-language

I translated all my theme strings and saved in .po and .mo files. I tested the implementation and it works fine, however I'm not sure how to let users choose their own language.

Are there any built-in functions to do this? How do I do it?

Comment: Language of whole site? Of front end? Registered users or any visitors? There is quite a range of things that might be required with languages, please clarify what exactly do you mean.

Comment: For any visitors

Answer (score 2):

Add filter in your child theme like this

```
add_filter( 'locale', 'set_my_locale' );
function set_my_locale( $lang ) {
  if ( 'gl' == $_GET['language'] ) {
    // set to Greenlandic
    return 'ka_GL';
  } else {
    // return original language
    return $lang;
  }
}
```

You can create the languages dropdown on front-end or any settings on backend where user can easily switch.
Then get the selected lang in $_GET variable and return that lang.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of translations in the WordPress website:

1. Label Translation in WordPress Core and Theme, for that gettext
   technique is useful (as mentioned by you .po and .mo files)
2. Content Translations for that you will need to add multi-lingual
   plugin to handle such feature. Good Example of such plugin are:

   - http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/
   - http://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/
   - More: http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/multilanguage

Answer (score 0):

Use a [multilingual plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/multilingual/) like [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/)